# How to get the ServiceBusMessage message size?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-sdk-.net

I am using Azure.Messaging.Servicebus and want to know if I can get the size of a ServiceBusMessage object? I am able to get the size of a batch if I use a batch object and keep adding the messages to it. Is there any way for me to know the size of the message that is represented by "ServiceBusMessage"?

Comment: Why would you want to know?

Comment: So that I can be aware beforehand whether it would fit the per-message size limits of the service bus type(premium or standard). I don't want to fail first and then get to know that it won't "fit".

Comment: But there are methods for that, to try add something to a batch, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusmessagebatch.tryaddmessage?view=azure-dotnet)

Comment: There is no supported way to measure a message outside of using `TryAdd` when adding to a batch, as Peter indicated.

Comment: @JesseSquire Using the batch means I must establish a connection to the service bus entity which I want to avoid and want to estimate things beforehand before the layer that communicates with the ASB. Another approximation is to get the byte count of the body and the byte count of each of the key-value of the headers.

Comment: That approximation would not be accurate, though it is a valid approach if you're comfortable with giving yourself a margin of error.  The size of a message depends on its AMQP-serialized format, which includes structure that is not in the model itself.     Why is it that you want to avoid making a connection?   Is this the only message being published?  Otherwise, I'd presume you'll need to connect at some point and would be sharing that same client/sender throughout the application.

Comment: @JesseSquire: I have a query on the internal working of the ASB SDK. If I use a sender of SB-A to create a message batch and then use the same message batch object to make a send call using a sender of SB-B, will it cause any issues?

Comment: No issues, with some caveats: creating the batch only requires a network operation on the first call in order to query Service Bus for the maximum allowed message size.   So long as both senders are publishing to queue/topic with the same size limit, everything will work as expected.   In the worst case, your batch will measure inaccurately because the size limits differ and you'll either be rejected for being too large or not be able to use the entire size allowed.

Comment: @ArunPrakashNagendran, how are you getting the size of the batch? Can you attach any link related to it please?

Comment: @bhanuprakash : As others have pointed out, kindly consider using ServiceBusMessageBatch.TryAddBatch  method.  If you want to know the size of the batch after each message has been added, you can check the property ServiceBusMessageBatch.SizeInBytes. Computing the batch size on our own is cumbersome and has lot of approximations.